# How to build .NET 6 framework on Raspberry Pi 4 which is based on Yocto (Dunfell)?

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi, yocto, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

Does anyone know how to build .NET 6 framework on Raspberry Pi 4 which is based on Yocto (Dunfell)?
Is it possible to do that?
Or what are the alternatives that I can have?

I have built Yocto image to my Raspberry Pi 4 and I want to run .NET program on the Pi. However, I only see many run .NET program on the Pi with Raspbian OS. So, I am wondering is it possible to run .NET program on the Yocto-based Pi? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check: this [link](https://github.com/RDunkley/meta-dotnet-core) , [this](https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Embedded_Linux_.NET_applications_with_Yocto#Embedded_Linux_.NET_applications_with_Yocto_and_OpenEmbedded) and [this](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/i-MX-8M-Nano-Enable-NET-Core-on-Yocto-Linux/m-p/1070733)

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM thanks, i'll try and see whether it works or not